# Possible XSS Attack in Java Script

Tags: javascript, dom, xss, fortify

Fortify on demand shows me this line of code as possible XSS problem

```
if (window.location.search != '') {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0,baseurl.length+1)+'currencyCode='+event.getCurrencyCode()+'&'+window.location.href.substr(baseurl.length+1);
} else {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0,baseurl.length)+'?currencyCode='+event.getCurrencyCode()+window.location.href.substr(baseurl.length);
}
```

I'm far from being JavaScript expert, but I need to fix this code.

Can you please help?

Comment: The code is trying to change the `url` of the current window. That's pretty nasty since the user might have no control over where the code takes them. Try building the `href` into a variable and then, _upon a deliberate user action_ (such as clicking a button), applying the `href` to `window.location`. If that doesn't work, you'll probably just have to use a hyperlink or something that opens a tab or window, instead of changing where the current window points to. There's also a chance it's triggering an XSS alert because the values you're fetching to build the href are cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think Fortify has found that event.getCurrencyCode() could be any length string and may contain a cross-site scripting attack that might send an unsuspecting user to a malicious site or cause the browser to load JavaScript that does bad things to the user.   You might be able to tell this by looking at the details tab of the finding in Fortify's Audit Workbench tool.

Assuming that the potentially malicious data could be supplied by event.getCurrencyCode, you need to whitelist validate this value either when the event is sourced or here in this code.  I'm going to bet that the spectrum values of currency code in this application is relatively small and each are of limited length so it should be directly possible to whitelist this value using Javascript's built in regex functionality.

As it stands now JavaScript will happily add a practically unlimited length string in that URL if it is supplied by the event, and with the UTF-8 character set there is a lot that an attacker can do (inlined JavaScript, etc.)

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the existing answer is incorrect, and ivy_lynx's comment doesn't really address the question.

Fortify On Demand is reporting a data flow vulnerability. This is a case where some data originates anywhere except from the programmer - and is reflected to the unaware end user's browser.

The potentially dangerous data **comes from:**

- event.getCurrencyCode()

You haven't posted enough source for us to know what this is, but a pretty good guess is that the function is supposed to return nothing other than an ISO currency code, or rather three, uppercase letters. ("EUR" or "JPY" etc.) Note I am making a big assumption here; I cannot see the code.

The potentially dangerous data **ends up** going into the browser's location.

The problem is that the developer has no guarantee what event will be sent, or that unexpected data might appear in that currency code.

The simplest fix is for you to transform the return value from "event.getCurrencyCode()" into guaranteed three uppercase letters. There is no known attack that can express in three such uppercase letters. So you could replace:

- event.getCurrencyCode()

with

- /^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$/.exec( event.getCurrencyCode() )

(reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp )

That will correctly build your URL if and only if event.getCurrencyCode() resolves to three uppercase letters like "USD". Otherwise, "null" will go into the URL at the point where the currency code was expected.

Obviously, you need to work with a real JavaScript developer to implement such a fix so that no further problems are introduced.